# Error: "Recipie terminated with error" - Visual Studio - LaTeX error

Tags: visual-studio, latex

I am trying to compile my file using LaTeX Workshop package in visual code. The error message "Recipe terminated with error, Source: LaTeX Workshop (Extension)" keeps appearing even after a successful build. Please see the image below.

[LaTeX Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEqy9.png)

When I click on open compiler error, nothing happens.

Please advise.

Thank you